# Clever Way To Get 2nd Item From Each Group In Array Of Hashes?

Tags: ruby

The problem would be easy to solve with a manual loop and a result array, which you add onto as you go.  But I'm looking for a more ruby-esque solution, probably something that uses inject or select. Here's the problem:

```rb
arr_of_hashes = [
  {id: 1, val: "blah1"},
  {id: 1, val: "blah2"},
  {id: 1, val: "blah3"},
  {id: 2, val: "blah4"},
  {id: 2, val: "blah5"},
  {id: 3, val: "blah6"},
  {id: 3, val: "blah7"},
  {id: 3, val: "blah8"},
  {id: 3, val: "blah9"}
]
```

"Groups" are defined by the "id" field in the hashes.  We are guaranteed each group has at least two items.  We want to return an array containing the 2nd item of each group:

```rb
output_should_be = [
  {id: 1, val: "blah2"},
  {id: 2, val: "blah5"},
  {id: 3, val: "blah7"}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I'm looking for a more ruby-esque solution". I guess you mean [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming):

```
arr_of_hashes.chunk { |h| h[:id] }.map { |id, hs| hs[1] }
#=> [{:id=>1, :val=>"blah2"}, {:id=>2, :val=>"blah5"}, {:id=>3, :val=>"blah7"}]
```

Use `group_by` if elements are not pre-ordered by *id*.

Comment: Very nice. I almost didn't post my `group_by` solution because you beat me to it with the nice `chunk` solution. I should really remember `chunk`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `group_by`:

```
arr_of_hashes.group_by{|h| h[:id]}.to_a.map{|id,a| a[1]}
```

Comment: +1 for this as it works the same on all versions. [**here is the proof**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=clever-way-to-get-2nd-item-from-each-group-in-array-of-hashes.rb&versions=*&run=true)